# PHP erorrs not showing

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fastcgi, fpm

All of a sudden my local machine has stopped showing 500 errors and instead provides a 503.
When looking in the error logs also, it displays the error "AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header" and then "AH01075: Error dispatching request to :" (full errors below)

This never used to happen and used to throw a 500 error and then log what the error was in the error logs.

To test this, I've literally got a PHP file where I am purposely missing out the end semi-colon to try and cause a 500.

My test code to throw the 500:

```
<?php
echo "Hello"
```

Full logs of what I'm getting instead of an error:

```
[Tue Oct 18 10:55:02.139915 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 275174] [client 127.0.0.1:47564] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Tue Oct 18 10:55:02.139977 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 275174] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:47564] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

I am using apache2 with PHP 7.3 FPM on a ubuntu 20.04 machine.

The main confusion I think with this is that it worked on Friday and showed me the errors, came in to work on Monday and it is no longer working.

Comment: You say *errors not showing*, but yes they are. You don't get the error you expect because something is wrong before. Maybe your PHP is broken, try restarting or even reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved this.
In my php ini I had the following xdebug parameters:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
```

I have commented this out and it now looks to be working with the page throwing a 500 rather than a 503, and the error logs display the actual php/code error

Answer (score 0):

I merely comment on the general case of `AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header` and `AH01075: Error dispatching request to :`. @José Carlos PHP is right that this indicates a php installation is broken.

Since there really isn’t good documentation anywhere that walks one through the various possible causes, for most users it’d be quicker to just recompile the php if you’re not quite in the same shoes as OP.